# Unable to create xml file

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to create an xml document with the information that is taken from a test. Basically I am using `{get; set:}` to get the information and when I walk through the program you see where the file information is passed through but I either get the error unable to create the xml document or it is created but is blank.

Here is the code:

```
public class XmlCreate
    {
        public string Types { set; get; }
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public bool done{ get; set; }


        public void SerializetoXml(IRepo repo)
        {       
            var filename = string.Format("{0}__{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), "Log.xml");
            var path =
                @"C:\TestDocs\artifacts";
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            var fullpath = Path.Combine(filename, path);
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer((typeof(IRepo))); 
            var textwriter = new StreamWriter(filename);
            serializer.Serialize(textwriter, repo);
            textwriter.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are all the classes implementing `IRepo` marked with a `Serializable` attribute? What exact error are you getting?

Comment: No I can not because it is an interface. And the error I get is that there was an error creating my xml document.

Comment: Check the InnerException for more information.  It will often tell you exactly why XML serialization failed.

Comment: @RogerN, Here is the error I get: {"The type 'Request' was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically."}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML serializer needs to know about all the object types it will encounter ahead of time.  If you're still trying to create the serializer using an interface instead of a class type then that might be part of the problem; an interface won't necessarily expose all of the public properties of your object.  Otherwise you need to make sure that any types which the XML serializer can't automatically infer from your properties (e.g. due to polymorphism) are included.  Use the XmlInclude attribute on your root object to inform the serializer about these types.  Example:

```
// XmlInclude is necessary because our class doesn't explicitly mention derived object
[XmlInclude(typeof(ObjectDerived))]
class MyRootClass {
    public ObjectBase { get; set; }
}
class ObjectBase {
    // some properties here
}
class ObjectDerived : ObjectBase {
    // more properties here
}
...
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyRootClass));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use full path as

```
Path.Combine(path, filename)
```

not the other way round.
your path name turned out to be wrong

**EDIT:**

You cant serialize by passing an Interface object.
You can modify your code as provided in this [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/SoftwareDoneRight/archive/2008/01/16/how-to-serialize-an-interface-using-the-xmlserializer.aspx)
or [this](http://ventspace.wordpress.com/2010/02/20/how-to-serialize-interfaces-in-net/)

Comment: I still get the error: "There was an error generating the XML document."